# How to get/iterate customers which have subscr_eot at my paypal?

Tags: paypal

I have a big list of subscriptions to verify if they subscr_eot ed. You can imagine that this could be tedious task. Is there an easy way to pull this via api or something else?

I thought to resend IPN and handle it via api but it can only re-send ipn if its not older then 30 days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the [TransactionSearch API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_NVP/) with a TRANSACTIONCLASS of Subscription.  That would return any payments you've received in the given time period that were from subscriptions.  You could cross-reference that with your own database (assuming you have subscription ID's saved) to see which ID's haven't been paid when they should have been.